# ArcGIS JS API: Token and Secure Resources

Tags: php, html, api, arcgis

I obtain my token with PHP code from this way:

1- POST petition to https://gis.server.com/portal/sharing/generateToken

2- with parameters: f=json, username=***, password=***, client=ip, ip=***, expiration=60

3- server response in json format a new token to access a secure resources, for example: tAGEfjIY7Risc2hFNgqXpvkdHbr1ObiFNlVL9ag2kO9gBoDDsUoSiMjbwjvJZfWjD36gLpqIiBNpGu7yPPPn1lAM-uGZTpDOEMPCxpZFHmlLq_noTXb--1fSjFo1cGC9z0hcgKiMrwvseMvyLbpDMQ..

In javascript code in my map I realize a secure resource call of feature layer:

fLayer = new FeatureLayer({
token: "tAGEfjIY7Risc2hFNgqXpvkdHbr1ObiFNlVL9ag2kO9gBoDDsUoSiMjbwjvJZfWjD36gLpqIiBNpGu7yPPPn1lAM-uGZTpDOEMPCxpZFHmlLq_noTXb--1fSjFo1cGC9z0hcgKiMrwvseMvyLbpDMQ..",
url: "https://gis.server.com/arcgis/rest/services/BASE/MapServer"
      });

The problem is that when I load the map, arcgis api show me a login dialog to load the resource and ignore my token, the idea of this code is not show the login dialog, in the api documents the class "FeatureLayer" have a parameter called "token" (string) I use this parameter in my code but don't work.

Answer (score 0):

The correct code is:

```
IdentityManager.registerToken({
    server: 'https://gis.server.com/arcgis/rest/services',
    token: '<token>'
});

fLayer = new FeatureLayer({
    url: "https://gis.server.com/arcgis/rest/services/BASE/Map/25"        
});
```

Comment: Do you if it's possible to connect to multiple servers? Something like this?

IdentityManager.registerToken({
    server: 'https://gis1.server.com/arcgis/rest/services',
    token: '<token1>'
});

IdentityManager.registerToken({
    server: 'https://gis2.server.com/arcgis/rest/services',
    token: '<token2>'
});